# @staticmethod vs @classmethod vs functions outside of class in Python

Tags: python

I have some static functions in a Python class.  The advantage to using the `@staticmethod` decorator is that it informs the reader that the method doesn't require any information from the class or instance.  However, what I've discovered is that if I have another static method that's called by my first static method, then even if I preface that static function with the `@staticmethod` decorator, I still have to call it by prefacing it with the class name, and not `self`.

Alternatively, I can go without any decorators and just call all the static functions with the class name prefix.  This makes the code easier to read.  Is there any reason why I shouldn't do this?

Comment: Doesn't it mean that this was a `classmethod` all along?

Comment: @tdelaney, I don't know what you call a function in a class that doesn't have a decorator and also doesn't have self as an argument.  A function like this though will work.

Comment: I think you'd call that a bug. You wouldn't be able to call it from an instance of the class, only from the class object itself. if class `Foo` had `def bar(): pass`, then neither `Foo().bar()` nor `self.bar()` from another method in `Foo` would work.

Comment: @matsuo_basho A method like that technically works because Python is super flexible, but just because it works it doesn't have to be a good idea to use this flexibility. Such a design will be highly confusing for other people who have to deal with your code.

Comment: `self` is just the convention for the name of the first parameter in an instance method, the one that is bound to the object that precedes the dot in a regular call. `class Foo: def bar(some_other_name): pass` is syntactically valid Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your method calls a static method on the class, then it *does* require information on the class. You have a class method, not a static method. By declaring it `@classmethod` (and adding the `cls` parameter), you not only properly inform the reader, you allow polymorphism. An inheritor can reimplement the called static method and change behavior.

Comment: I'm beginning to understand that I should either put them outside of the class or label them as `@classmethod`.  To help me decide, what does this statement mean exactly - 'your method calls a static method ON THE CLASS'?

Comment: You said _I still have to call it by prefacing it with the class name_. That's calling a static method on the class. If we have `MyClass`, `static_method_1` and `static_method_2`. `static_method_1` needs to use `MyClass.static_method_2` - calling the static method on the class. So it needs the class and that means its better to be a class method. Inheritors, mix-ins or even later refactoring will all benefit.

Comment: Ok, so the only remaining question is how do I decide whether it's correct to have them as a `@classmethod` or to put them outside of the class.  It seems that since they are only used by the class, it's correct to leave them inside.  Or is that an irrelevant reason?  Is it purely a matter of preference at that point?  Reason why it's important is that I currently already have helper functions that are applied by methods from different classes.

Comment: @matsuo_basho : Leaving `classmethod` in a class allows for customization of its behavior by subclasses. Putting such methods outside of a class, as functions, allows for reusing them by unrelated code. Depending on your current context and predictable future of the project - either can be better solution.

Answer (score 3):

Python's static methods are intended for methods that are part of a class, and can be called as either a class method or an instance method: *both* `Class.the_method()` and `self.the_method()` would work. When the static method is called, it is not given an implicit first argument:

```py
class Example:
  def instance_method_example(self, arguments):
    ...

  @classmethod
  def class_method_example(cls, arguments):
    ...

  @staticmethod
  def static_method_example(arguments):
    ...
```

If you merely want to create a helper function that is used within your class, do not use `@staticmethod`. Define a free function outside of the class. For example:

```py
class Example:
  def some_method(self, argument):
    return _helper(argument, self.x)

def _helper(a, b):
  ...
```

---

The background of static methods in Python is the following: when you access an attribute of an object `x.attribute` or `getattr(x, 'attribute')`, then this name is looked up in the instance dict or the class dict. If an object is found in the class dict, it is checked whether that object is a “descriptor”: an object that describes how this attribute behaves, not an object that would be directly returned. Descriptors have dunder-methods like `__get__`, `__set__`, and `__del__` that are invoked depending on whether the descriptor is accessed, assigned to, or deleted with the `del` operator.

Functions – the things you declare with `def` – are descriptors. By default, the `__get__` descriptor binds the function to the instance argument (typically called `self`) and returns the bound function, so that it can be invoked as a method. But the various decorators change this behaviour:

- a `@classmethod def` binds to the class object, not the instance
- a `@staticmethod def` does not bind to any object and just returns the underlying function directly
- a `@property` *invokes* the underlying function to retrieve a value

These differences are (partially) visible when looking at the repr() of the bound methods. With the first Example class:

- `instance_method_example`

  - with class: `Example.instance_method_example`
    is `<function Example.instance_method_example at 0x7f1dfdd6fd30>`,
    the unbound function
  - with instance: `<function Example.instance_method_example at 0x7f1dfdd6fd30>`
    is `<bound method Example.instance_method_example of <__main__.Example object at 0x7f1dfdddcb80>>`,
    a method bound to the instance
- `class_method_example`

  - with class: `Example.class_method_example`
    is `<bound method Example.class_method_example of <class '__main__.Example'>>`,
    a method bound to the class
  - with instance: `Example().class_method_example`
    is `<bound method Example.class_method_example of <class '__main__.Example'>>`,
    also a method bound to the class
- `static_method_example`

  - with class: `Example.static_method_example`
    is `<function Example.static_method_example at 0x7f1dfdd6fe50>`,
    the unbound function
  - with instance: `Example().static_method_example`
    is `<function Example.static_method_example at 0x7f1dfdd6fe50>`,
    also the unbound function

As a table:

| invoked on… | no decorator | `@classmethod` | `@staticmethod` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| … instance | bound to instance | bound to class | unbound |
| … class | unbound | bound to class | unbound |

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer my question directly.  I want to keep the function within the class because it is only invoked by methods within that class.  It would be organizationally confusing to put the function outside of the class.  This helper function will also itself invoke another helper function.  I can avoid labeling these functions with a `@staticmethod` decorators and just call with the classname prefix.  What is wrong with this approach?

Comment: @matsuo_basho `static_method_example` is never the name of a function in this example program. `Example.static_method_example` is a name of it, as is `Example().static_method_example`, `self.static_method_example` in an instance method or `cls.static_method_example` in a class method.

Comment: @matsuo_basho By accessing a normal (instance) method through the class object you happen to get an unbound method that you could use as an ordinary function. But this is a pretty confusing design because you're using instance methods for something other than instance methods. Your approach might look easier to you, but it's far more confusing for everyone else. The normal Python way to implement helpers is to use separate functions, not methods in a class.